# Challenge to developing an AJAX interface to Virtuemart?

Tags: ajax, joomla, virtuemart

We are working with a client that is considering developing an AJAX interface to a Virtuemart deployment within a Joomla.

We are looking to create a more dynamic ordering environment. They would like to have a visual representation of the product show on the screen as the visiting customer chooses options and features. They would also like it to post the resulting price.

Is this the right tool? Has anyone had success developing an AJAX front end for Virtuemart?

Answer (score 1):

The question if Virtuemart is the right tool does not depend on the customisation of the frontend checkout process. We have done major modifications/ rewrites to the checkout as well as product pages and this is fairly easy, as most of the code is straightforward organised into files and doesn't have too many dependencies.

If the data model and backend as well as interactions with other modules works for you, then I think its the right component. Don't expect this to make your frontend any easier.

I would suggest to create a new component and copy aqnd paste code into it as you see fit, probably largely around
* address handling
* checkout saving
* email processing

All else I would just write from scratch.